# Proof By Induction With Integration Problem

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, induction, factorial

I am required to prove this formula by induction$$ \int x^k e^{\lambda x} = \frac{(-1)^{k+1}k!}{\lambda^{k+1}} + \sum_{i=0}^k \frac{(-1)^i k^\underline{i}}{\lambda^{i+1}}x^{k-i}e^{\lambda x}$$
where $k^{\underline i}$ is a falling factorial $k(k-1) \cdots (k-i+1)$ (assuming this to be equal to 1 when $i=0$) and the integral $\int f$ is defined as $\int_0^x f(\xi) d\xi$

My first problem results when trying for $k=0$ as an initial value, I get LHS: $\frac{e^{\lambda x}}{\lambda}$ and RHS: $\frac{e^{\lambda x}}{\lambda} - \frac{1}{\lambda}$ I assumed that as I have solved an integral the lambda on the RHS could be incorporated in the "+C" that the integral produced on the LHS but doesn't the $\int f$ definition mean that there is no +C?

Help would also be appreciated to any steps towards solving for $k=n+1$

Comment: Regarding $k=n+1$, have you tried partial integration? If so, what did it give you?

Comment: Solving by parts I get $\int x^{n+1} e^{\lambda x} = \frac{x^{n+1} e^{\lambda x}}{\lambda} \space- (\frac{n+1}{\lambda})\int x^n e^{\lambda x}$ and subbing in for $k=n$ gives $\int x^{n+1} e^{\lambda x} = \frac{x^{n+1} e^{\lambda x}}{\lambda} \space+ \frac{(-1)^{(n+1)+1}(n+1)!}{\lambda^{(n+1)+1}} + (\frac{n+1}{\lambda}) \sum_{i=0}^k \frac{(-1)^i k^\underline{i}}{\lambda^{i+1}}x^{k-i}e^{\lambda x}$ which looks promising but I don't know how to manipulate the sum to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

According to your definition of the operator $\int$, the LHS for $k=0$ becomes $$\int e^{\lambda x}=\int_0^x e^{\lambda\xi}\; d\xi = \left[\frac{e^{\lambda\xi}}{\lambda}\right]_{\xi = 0}^{\xi = x}=\frac{e^{\lambda x}}{\lambda}-\frac1\lambda$$

And working out the right-hand side for $k=0$ will give you the same result.